# Aura Attribute of Type Object is Supported in Flows?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, visual-workflow, sobject, aura-attribute

I am working on a Flow Screen and trying to assign a value to a lightning component attribute from a variable in the flow. The flow screen allows me to select the lightning component but it doesn't display the attribute that I want to use. The attribute is of the type Account[]. All of this is based on this [article](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_flow_tips_map.htm). How can I make this attribute accessible in the flow?

Component:

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens" 
access="global" >

<aura:attribute name="accounts" type="Account[]" access="global"/>

</aura:component>
```

Designer:

```
<design:component>
<design:attribute name='accounts' label='Accounts' />
</design:component>
```

[image: Flow]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a bug in Salesforce that removes sObject collection attributes from Flow Designer when you are in an org with an assigned package prefix (which I believe is your situation).  More here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=9060G0000005YOSQA2

I don't know if SF is even aware of it.